# Is there any difference between Unit in Kotlin and void of Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

In the documentation of kotlin ,it is given that `Unit` type corresponds to `void` in Java . But Java documentation clearly mention void is a keyword . Going by the naming convention of keyword,`Unit` bears no resemblance to it at all.

Is there any subtle difference between both of them ?

Comment: One difference is Unit is actually a value in Kotlin, whereas Java's void isn't actually a value (you can't get an instance of `void`; they had to make a `Void` class, so you could use `Void` in places that expected a value). Kotlin's unit only has one instance, and you can use it like any other piece of data.

Comment: In Java you have the void keyword and the Void type, Unit replaces them both. It has a single instance value which is implied, while the Void type has no instance at all and forces you to write the null value. Unit makes it easier to write generic functions compared to Java.